# Check a field in MySql from a php md5 string

Tags: php, mysql, md5, compare

I'm trying to validate a pair of data columns on mysql from my php page across **md5** function.
I've encrypted the string **"helloworld"** with php **md5** function and attempted to compare it with **MYSQL MD5** function but it won't work.
I do this because in the database there is a pair of strings **"hello"** and **"world"** needs to be compared with my php string, so:

```
<?php
$str_a = "hello";
$str_b = "world";
$str_encrypted = md5 ($str_a.$str_b);

// note "first_col" is "hello" and "second_col" is "world"
$sql = "UPDATE `my_table` SET `checked_col` = '1' WHERE MD5(CONCAT(first_col,second_col)) = '$str_encrypted' LIMIT 1;";
$res = mysql_query ($sql) or die (mysql_error());

($res) ? print "true" : print "false";
?>
```

This code return me false, and the database don't **UPDATE** the column **checked column**, but not **mysql_error** problems are returned.

Could the **md5** from php generate a different **MD5** from MYSQL?

a similar code written by a friend worked in the same server, but i don't have to much experience to see where is the difference

can someone explain me where I'm wrong?
thanks!

Comment: Not sure what your problem is, but I would choose a more transparent means of debugging. Verify each piece of the process yourself, instead of assuming things are working as you expect. So first output $str_a.$str_b and  CONCAT(first_col,second_col) and make sure they are the same input, as you expect they are. Then MD5 them both and verify visually whether they evaluate to the same thing...and so on, so that you verify things are working as expected each step of the way.

Comment: thanks, if you think the query should work i'll recheck from the begin!

Comment: P.S. I've heard that MD5 is pretty much a cracked encryption these days (at least if you don't seed the hash or you don't do nested md5 calls like md5(md5(md5('password'))) ), so keep in mind that using a naked md5() function call may be more appropriate to sanitized data storage than secure encryption, for which you might want to use something else.

Comment: soob! u was right! thanks for help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wouldn't mix & match MD5 functions.  Probably simpler to consider any md5 function a one-way street.  So modify it to be:

```
$str_concat = $str_a.$str_b;

// note "first_col" is "hello" and "second_col" is "world"
$sql = "UPDATE `my_table` SET `checked_col` = '1' WHERE
     MD5(CONCAT(first_col,second_col)) = MD5('$str_concat') LIMIT 1;";
```

Or just make the sql match exactly, for simplicity.

```
// Skip the php concatenation.

// note "first_col" is "hello" and "second_col" is "world"
$sql = "UPDATE `my_table` SET `checked_col` = '1' WHERE 
    MD5(CONCAT(first_col,second_col)) = MD5(CONCAT('$str_a','$str_b')) LIMIT 1;";
```

Comment: this is a great idea i haven' had!<br/>
unfortunately, I can't use this smart solution because my php md5 string came from an email like an activation code, so i need to hide the string first with php md5, send via email, and then check it from the query page.

Answer (score 1):

The only way that `MD5` in `MySQL` would return a different hash then the `MD5` function in `PHP` is if the [character set](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset.html) in `MySQL` is different.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following query:

```
SELECT  MD5(CONCAT(first_col,second_col))
FROM    mytable
WHERE   first_col = 'hello'
        AND second_col = 'world'
```

and make sure it returns `fc5e038d38a57032085441e7fe7010b0`

Also check that the case of `MD5` returned by `PHP` and `MySQL` match.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that your $res is false because there is nothing to update. If you have previously run your SQL command and updated the row, it will not update again if checked_col is still 1. Since mysql_query doesn't update anything, it will return false.

You could include a where clause to ignore previously checked (validated) rows.

You probably don't want to use the result of your update to determine whether validation was successful, perhaps you want to use a select instead.

Answer (score 0):

** The only solution I found is to insert the password (or update the table) using the md5 hash part of php's function library, that way when you compare the hash to the database it works.  All other attempts to match an md5 hash from php with the md5 function of mySQL fail.

If anybody knows why (I believe older versions of php and mysql dont have this problem) this happens, I would love to know - thanks, rick